# Null pointer exception is occuring while initializing the Textview using Butterknife

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, butterknife

I have the following code:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @InjectView(R.id.testTv)
    TextView textView;            

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        args.putString("product_url");
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_userprofile_myaccount, container, false);

        ButterKnife.inject(getActivity(), rootView);

        textView.setText("Hello");

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

}
```

Error is occuring on the line with `textview.setText("Hello");`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read the [document](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/#non-activity) carefully :)

not:

```
ButterKnife.inject(getActivity(), rootView);
```

change to:

```
ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);
```